# How to recreate an expired app certificate?

Tags: windows-store-apps

Created several app packages for a windows store app some time ago in order to show a client the progression of the application.  Now I would like to load a much older version of the application onto the device, however PowerShell says that the certificate has expired and thus the application does not install.  Is there a way to regen the certificate without recreating the entire app package and/or get around an expired certificate and just manually install the app on the device?

Comment: Hopefully someone has a better answer, but I have always just recreated the app package.